# How to convert char to int and find the sum of characters from .txt file

Tags: c++, input

I have a text file:

```
Carly:Cat:ABCCCCE.
```

I need to convert the last set of characters: `ABCCCCE` into integers and display their sum. I need to set the values to:

```
A = 15, B = 5, C = 6, D = 8, E = 2
```

The issue I am having is that these characters are in a .txt file and I am quite unfamiliar with how to extract ONLY the last elements of the line.

I have attempted to create a function to set the values of each letter `A through to E`, and have used this code to attempt to add them the values of these characters `ABCCCCE` together:

```
int Return_Complexity(char character)
{
switch (character)
{
case 'a':
    return 15;
    break;
case 'b':
    return 5;
    break;
case 'c':
    return 6;
    break;
case 'd':
    return 8;
    break;
case 'e':
    return 2;
    break;
default:
    return 0; 
}
}


void printComplexity()
{
ifstream file("Customers.txt");
vector<int> values;
char character;
while (file >> character)
{
    int result = Return_Complexity(tolower(character));
    if (result > 0) //if its a-e
        values.push_back(result);
}
int Result = accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 1); //add together
std::cout << Result << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    printComplexity();
  
    return 0;
}
```

From the values assigned to each character, I would want the output to be:

```
46
```

However, the function returns:

```
1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1-5 is quite different from 15, 5, 6, 8, 2

Comment: `tolower()` gives `a-e`, but you test for `A-E`

Comment: Read file line by line (using `std::getline`). Then in each line find last occurrence of char ':' (using `std::string::find_last_of()` for example), letters after it would be your data. This should work unless file format is more complicated, but you do not give enough info then.

Comment: @OlafDietsche once I make those two changes that you suggested, I now receive an output of ``310``

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is two things you are doing it wrong.

1. Indentation
2. Using all characters from the line to calculate sum.

You have mentioned that you only want to use the last section of the line but there is no code to distinguish the last section. Therefore it adds all the characters from "carly" & "cat".

As @Slava mentioned on a comment, you need to read each line from the file & get the position of last `:`.

```cpp
void printComplexity()
{
    ifstream file("Customers.txt");
    vector<int> values;
    string line;
    // Read file line-by-line until reaches EOF
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        // Find last occurrence of `:`
        size_t last_pos = line.find_last_of(':');
        // Create new string that only contains desired section
        // and iterate over it to get value.
        string word (line, last_pos);
        for (auto& ch : word) {
            int result = Return_Complexity(tolower(ch));
            values.push_back(result);  
        }
    }
    int Result = accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0); //add together
    std::cout << Result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: After implementing your answer, I receive an output of ``183``

Comment: @bean Are you sure you are using the same inputs? Or made change to the `Return_Complexity()`? I have tested it myself and it (origianlly) returns 47 due to passing `1` to the `accumulate()` as third argument. I have fixed the code from the answer now.
The answer however does includes `:` & `.` to the parsed string. So you may want to check that or remove it from the string.

Answer (score 0):

the code is reading the whole file
thus even `Ca`rly:`Ca`t:ABCCCCE. are counted with Carly:Cat:`ABCCCCE`.
you must wait for `character` to match delimter(`:` in this case) twice
then expect the comming of `ABCCCCE.`